# How to append items to DOM with jquery coming from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, local-storage

I have a question. I have an input field and store the inputs in localstorage. On click (on 'add') I am adding inputs to localstorage and want to immediately append it to my ul element. I cant just append the current input as it would disappear on page reload but when I get items from localstorage, its not being displayed correctly. Ive researched this but whatever I tried, I keep getting weird results. I included the code below and also made a jsfiddle. Thanks very much!

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codingcodingcoding/41mztdnu/

html:

```
<input id="title"/>
<input id="text"/>
<button id="button">Add</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

js:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
    var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];

    var newTodos = {
        "title": title,
        "text": text
    }
    todos.push(newTodos);

    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))

    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        $("#output").append("<li>" + todo.text + "</li>")
    })

})
```

update: the code below does show me the current added item but disappears on page refresh since only the todo list is persistent, here 'current' cant be the whole list.

```
localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
var current=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"))
$("#output").append("<li>" + current.text + "</li>")
```

Comment: Try changing it to `var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos") || "[]");`

Comment: Each time you click the button it adds another li item into storage, so on the next time you click it adds x number of lis from local storage, don't you just want to append a new li with the value of var newTodos on each click ?

Comment: you need to do `$("#output").empty();` before your `forEach` loop

Comment: @Ryan Ive updated my question reg. what you said. the problem is when I add only the new item- it looks fine at first, but on page refresh it all disappears. Thats my problem- I want to add new items but want the whole list to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make another function that just populates the list so you can use it immediately when the page loads, so it doesn't start with an empty list. Make sure this function empties the existing items in the list before adding more.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var title = $("#title").val();
  var text = $("#text").val();
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  var newTodos = {
    "title": title,
    "text": text
  }
  todos.push(newTodos);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
  populateList();
});

function populateList() {
  var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  $("#output").empty();
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    $("#output").append("<li>" + todo.text + "</li>")
  })
}

populateList();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/41mztdnu/7/

Comment: thank you, it works now!! Do you happen to know by any chance how to make it so the new item is gonna be added first, not (as currently last) in the list?